# How can I do a non-greedy (backtracking) match with OneOrMore etc. in pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse a partially standardized street address into it's components using `pyparsing`. I want to non-greedy match a street name that may be N tokens long.

For example:

```
444 PARK GARDEN LN
```

Should be parsed into:

```
number: 444
street: PARK GARDEN
suffix: LN
```

How would I do this with PyParsing? Here's my initial code:

```
from pyparsing import *

def main():
    street_number = Word(nums).setResultsName('street_number')
    street_suffix = oneOf("ST RD DR LN AVE WAY").setResultsName('street_suffix')
    street_name = OneOrMore(Word(alphas)).setResultsName('street_name')

    address = street_number + street_name + street_suffix
    result = address.parseString("444 PARK GARDEN LN")
    print result.dump()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but when I try parsing it, the street suffix gets gobbled up by the default greedy parsing behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the negation, `~`, to check to see if the upcoming `street_name` is actually a `street_suffix`.

```
from pyparsing import *

street_number = Word(nums)('street_number')
street_suffix = oneOf("ST RD DR LN AVE WAY")('street_suffix')
street_name = OneOrMore(~street_suffix + Word(alphas))('street_name')

address = street_number + street_name + street_suffix
result = address.parseString("444 PARK GARDEN LN")
print result.dump()
```

In addition, you don't *have* to use `setResultsName`, you can simply use the syntax above. IMHO it leads to a much cleaner grammar definition.

Comment: Very nice answer, wish I could give a second upvote for the tip on alternative form for `setResultsName`. To the OP: parsing street addresses is extremely complicated, there is a sample at the pyparsing wiki (http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/streetAddressParser.py/135329743/streetAddressParser.py) that might give you more of a jump start.

Comment: The negation was a great time saver