# Non-greedy matching of Word in pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing, non-greedy

I would like to match a word that ends with either `_foo` or `_bar`. I wrote this:

```
identifier = Word(alphanums + '_')
string     = identifier + Suppress('_') + oneOf('foo bar')
```

Unfortunately, I realized `identifier` is greedy and consume all the keyword.

How do I force `identifier` to be not greedy?

```
$ string.parseString('a_keyword_foo')
ParseException: Expected "_" (at char 13), (line:1, col:14)
```

Some valid keywords:

```
a_keyword_foo          # ['a_keyword', 'foo']
foo_bar_foo            # ['foo_bar',   'foo']
bar_bar                # ['bar',       'bar']
```

Some invalid keywords:

```
keyword_foo_foobar
2keywords_bar          # The leading number is perhaps another question...
foo _bar 
_foo
```

Comment: Non-greedy matching is discussed at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938540/pyparsing-non-greedy-match. Good luck!

Comment: @Jurgenfd, I've read that. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know for what you're looking, you can use [`pp.SkipTo`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/share/view/1552279):

```
In [38]: foo_or_bar = Literal('foo') | Literal('bar')

In [39]: string = SkipTo(Literal('_') + foo_or_bar) + Literal('_') + foo_or_bar

In [42]: string.parseString('frumpy _foo')
Out[42]: (['frumpy ', '_', 'foo'], {})
```

---

Unfortunately, you also get this behavior, though:

```
In [44]: string.parseString('frumpy _foo _foo')
Out[44]: (['frumpy ', '_', 'foo'], {})
```

in case the pattern can appear more than once.

The problem is that `pyparsing` doesn't do lookahead. If you're concerned about the second case too, you'll have to define it as one or more things ending with underscore + foo or bar (as above), and then take the last one.

Comment: Nice, I did not know `SkipTo`, but `frumpy _foo` is not one keyword, but 2.

Comment: @nowox I don't understand your comment (or the question). Can you perhaps add to your question inputs and required outputs?

Comment: I added some examples to the question.

Comment: If using SkipTo here, add a failOn expression (something like `failOn=White()`) to avoid skipping too far.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to/can switch to the re api you can use non-greedy matching there:

```
    import re
    p = re.compile (r"""([a-z_]+?)        # lazy matching identifier
                         _ (bar|foo)      # _ with foo or bar
       """, re.VERBOSE)
    subject_string = 'a_hello_foo'
    m = p.match( subject_string )
    print "groups:", m.groups()
    print "group 1:", m.group(1)
```

Within pyparsing there is also the possibility to use regex.

Comment: I'd probably go with using `pyparsing.Regex` here, although you could also use plain old Word, and add a condition to accept only those words that end with '_bar' or '_foo', something like `string = identifier().addCondition(lambda t: t[0].endswith('_foo') or t[0].endswith('_bar')`

Comment: yes, and then postprocess to trim the trailing chars. Should be easy ;-)

Comment: ??? - no post-processing required. The Word expression will only get the body of the identifier, not any additional trailing characters. And I'm pretty sure the OP *wanted* the '_foo' or '_bar' endings, so no need to trim them either.